# Connect multiple clients to one server

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to connect all my clients to one server. I've done some research and found out that the easiest way to do it is create a new thread for every client that connects to the server. But I am already stuck on the part where a client disconnects and reconnect.

Client

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private static int port = 40021;
    private static String ip = "localhost";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        String command, temp;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
        while (true) {
            Scanner scanneri = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Enter any command");
            command = scanner.nextLine();
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            p.println(command);
            temp = scanneri.nextLine();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }

}
```

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String command, temp;
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(40021);
        while (true) {
            Socket ss = s1.accept();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                command = sc.nextLine();
                temp = command + " this is what you said.";
                PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
                p.println(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect once it works correctly but as soon as I disconnect the client and try to reconnect (or connect a second client) it does not give an error or anything it just does not function. I am trying to keep it as basic as possible.

The output with one client:
[image: Correct output]

When I try and connect a second client: 
[image: Output with 2 clients connected]

I hope someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, based on your research you should have created a new thread for each client connection on the server. Where is the part where you are doing that?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've been following programming college for a few months now and I dont understand threading. So I hope someone could explain it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server currently handles only 1 client at a time, use threads for each client, Modify your server code like this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(40021);
    while (true)
    {
        ss = s1.accept();
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String command, temp;
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
                    while (sc.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        command = sc.nextLine();
                        temp = command + " this is what you said.";
                        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
                        p.println(temp);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but this does not solve the problem. It does not give an exception.

Comment: @JesseVlietveld , when your main function throws IOException the program exits when the client disconnects as the exception is thrown out of the main function which shutsdown your server, you could remove that and place a try catch inside alone or you could keep that there unneccessarily and place this inside

Comment: I dont think you understand me. The problem is that it does not give an error or exception. It just does not show anything. I will update my post with some more detail.

Comment: @JesseVlietveld why is your client running forever?, it never disconnects

Comment: Because it is supposed to run 24/7 so I can give it commands whenever I want. I updated the post btw.

Comment: @JesseVlietveld you are trying to connect two clients at the same time but your server can handle only one client at a time, inorder to do this you need to thread it ill edit it in a min

Comment: Thats correct. I need to give instructions to all the clients that are running.

Comment: no probs @JesseVlietveld, take a look at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=br_TEuE8TbY to learn more about multi threading if you are new to it :)

Comment: Just 1 more quick question. Is there a way to send a PrintStream to all active threads?

Comment: @JesseVlietveld what do you mean?, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: With this line I print to the PrintStream        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(       ss.getOutputStream());
p.println(temp); Is there a way to send this to all active threads? Without the thread doing anything.

Comment: @JesseVlietveld you would need to do few more modifications to your client and server, here is a similiar example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr02nyPqLBU

Comment: Thanks I will check it out! Is there a way to contact you if I can not manage to do it?